# Command line suspend for a pre-determined amount of time

Tags: command-line, suspend

How can I suspend from the command line for a pre-determined amount of time?

For example, in the terminal i can do "pm-suspend", and that suspends the computer.
But I want the computer to come out of this suspend a couple of days later, on its own, and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Can you give an example about what you mean by 'suspend'? I have a response but I wanted to make sure I understand your question before posting.

Comment: suspend is a computer state in which the computer spends incredibly little amount of energy while retaining some sort of power.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want Suspend-to-RAM ([ACPI S3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface#Global_states)).

Here is what works for me.

```
sudo rtcwake --verbose  --mode mem --time `date '+%s' -d '+ 130 minutes'`
```

The subcommand passed as the argument to `--time` is the easy way to generate the int timestamp required by that argument.

Note that on my system, I have to cheat a bit: the command above just suspends for 10 minute -- must be related to the internal clock not using UTC.

Note also that `--mode` can take other values:

- `disk` to Suspend-to-disk (ACPI S4)
- `no` to just set the alarm but does not suspend
- (there are other options, see `man rtcwake`)

If you use `no`, you can then check the state of the alarm with

```
cat /proc/driver/rtc
```

Look at the first 6 lines:

```
rtc_time     : 10:34:45
rtc_date     : 2012-02-29
alrm_time    : 10:44:36
alrm_date    : 2012-02-29
alarm_IRQ    : yes
alrm_pending : no
```

`alrm_pending` always display `no` for me, go figure... But the interesting one is the `alarm_IRQ`, which is set to `yes` when an alarm is set.

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/8/rtcwake

Comment: to suspend for 20 seconds: rtcwake -m mem -s 20

Comment: Adding `-l` or `--local` to @Pierre-Antoine's `rtcwake` command makes the command work correctly and sleep for the expected amount of time.

Comment: @ScottSeverance: `-l` typically would work for dual-boot systems, since Windows requires the RTC to be set to local time; there's no reason not to have the RTC set to UTC when using only Linux.